# Why can't I import my files in VSCode in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This morning I tried to import a file that I created into another file but the file name that I am trying to import has the yellow scribble line under it. I know this is an import error but I can't fix it. I am working in VSCode on Windows 10 in python. The files are in the same directory.

I tried to import the path of the file but it doesn't work.

[image]

I had an old working file which requires me to import another file into it but now it doesn't work as well. Is this a new bug in VSCode?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the error in the img show that the .txt file can't be found, maybe is because your current working directory is different from the folder where your code reside, try with the absolute/full path to that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try : `path/to/python3 -m path/to/script.py`

or just specify the full path : 'C://Users/quina//...//word.txt'

Maybe try to use the normale python3 IDLE or throught the terminal just to understand you error.

There is no word.txt in 'Visual Studio Projects' folder